# Callback function is not executing

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I'm learning about callback functions, and I have this code where I pass the initial function in as a parameter, into the final function.

I can't seem to work out why this isn't woking?  It's supposed to turn the body element red, and also log the variable 'body' to the console.

```
let body = document.querySelector('body');

function callbackFunction() {
body.style.background = "red";
}

function anotherFunction(callback) {
console.log(body);
}

anotherFunction(callbackFunction);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the passed callback is never executed.

```
function anotherFunction(callback) { //<-- callback received
    console.log(body);
                                     //<-- ...but never executed
}
```

Just add an invocation:

```
function anotherFunction(callback) {
    console.log(body);
    callback(); //<-- call the callback
}
```